# ACF creating multi field, custom field type

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have created custom field type following this documentation https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/creating-a-new-field-type/ and I have below fields:

- YouTube ID(input type text)
- Submit Button(input type submit)
- Title(input type text)
- Description(input type text)
- Thumbnail URL(input type text)
- Upload Date(input type text)
- Duration minute(input type number)
- Duration seconds(input type number)

I have saw this question, [Advanced Custom Fields – Custom Field Type with multiple inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23180104/advanced-custom-fields-custom-field-type-with-multiple-inputs) and [ACF: Creating Custom Field Type store two values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53795089/acf-creating-custom-field-type-store-two-values). I am expecting that I could do it this way when setting the fields.

```
<input type="text"
  name="<?php echo esc_attr($field['name']['youtube-id'])?>"
  value="<?php echo esc_attr($field['value']['youtube-id'])?>"
/>
 <input type="text"
  name="<?php echo esc_attr($field['name']['youtube-title'])?>"
  value="<?php echo esc_attr($field['value']['youtube-title'])?>"
/>
...
```

But this give me an error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`$field['name']` is a string. Thus, doing `$field['name']['foo']` or the equivalent `'string'['foo']` is illegal in PHP and will raise the error. You may want to consider something like this instead:

```php
<input type="text"
  name="<?php echo esc_attr($field['name']); ?>"
  value="<?php echo esc_attr($field['value']); ?>"
/>
```

Comment: but I have more than one field, how would i create the other field?

Comment: Where is your other field? How does it integrate with this field?

Comment: you can see it, in the render field method, i have multiple fields

Comment: You'd want to look at making `$field['value']` an array, and then have the values like `$field['value']['foo']`.

Comment: how do i do this?